# Gmail's filters for auto-labeling outgoing mail

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

I'm getting my mail in Gmail from base account and four additional accounts, fetched via POP3. For each account Gmail offered (when adding) auto-labelling mechanism, which I used. This seems to be working perfectly only for incoming mail and fails for outgoing mail.

In particular:

- all e-mails received via base or any of these external accounts are correctly labeled,
- mails sent via any of external e-mails are only labelled, when I reply to someone's mail,
- if I start new message and send it, it is not labelled at all,
- mail sent through base `@gmail.com` address is not labeled correctly in any circumstances.

Here is an example -- only replies are correctly labelled, initial e-mails are not:

[image]

To "fix" these problems, I have created several Gmail's filters. One even in two copies:

[image]

In brings no help.

Is this some kind of bug or by-design and results, that I'm getting are correct? Or am I missing something or doing something wrong? Even if auto-labelling mechanism is intend to work for incoming mail only, then why my filters does not work?

Comment: Do you want to know if it is only possible for incoming emails (which you already figured out yourself) or do you want to have a solution for outgoing emails?

Comment: I think, you can figure out (from the fact, that I wrote about my unsuccessful attempts to "fix" this), that I'm willing to find a solution, that will work for outgoing e-mails! :> Unfortunately, [Al E.'s answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/74818/21486) explains, that this is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gmail filters only fire on incoming messages, so this would seem to be working as designed.